# Subset list, keep names

Tags: r, list

I have list `out` like this:

```
u <- list(a = list(b = 1, c = 2), 
          x = list(k = list(ka = 1, kb = 3), 
                   l = list(la = 1, la = 4)))
v <- list(a = list(b = 1, c = 2), 
          x = list(m = list(ma = 5, mb = 8), 
                   n = list(na = 5, nb = 8)))
w <- list(a = list(b = 1, c = 2), 
          x = list(o = list(oa = 4, ob = 1), 
                   p = list(pa = 8, pb = 0)))

out <- list(u, v, w)
```

I would like to create another list where there are elements `k, l, m, n, o, p` and names of the list elements are preserved. I found a solution, but looks sub-optimal:

```
x <- lapply(out, function(y) y[['x']])

o <- list()
for (a in x) {
  o <- c(o, a)  
}

> str(o, max.level = 1)

List of 6
 $ k:List of 2
 $ l:List of 2
 $ m:List of 2
 $ n:List of 2
 $ o:List of 2
 $ p:List of 2
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop could be replaced with `unlist`:

```
res <- unlist( lapply(out,"[[","x"), recursive=FALSE)
identical(res,o)
# [1] TRUE
```

My `lapply` is the same as in the OP; it's just a shortcut.

---

As @akrun suggested, you could more closely mirror the OP's loop with

```
do.call("c", lapply(out, '[[', 'x'))
```